# preceding nth row without self-joins

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a large query that results in following:

```
Date      Cost
------------------
6-Oct    24.05
5-Oct    34.56
4-Oct    24.76
3-Oct    12.89
2-Oct    11.34
1-Oct    21.76
30-Sept  32.89
29-Sept  11.34
```

I am trying to have the following using windows

```
Date      Cost   Previous_week
-------------------------------
6-Oct    24.05   32.89
5-Oct    34.56   11.34
4-Oct    24.76   NULL
3-Oct    12.89   NULL
2-Oct    11.34   NULL
1-Oct    21.76   NULL
30-Sept  32.89   NULL
29-Sept  11.34   NULL
```

Seems that window functions can be used only for aggregations, Is there another way that I can get 7th preceding row ?

I don't want to do self-joins.

Comment: `array_agg` with window and then pick first one. sound weird

Comment: `lag(cost, 7) over (order by date)`. Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column.

Comment: its a computed table , just an example. thanks for the tip

Comment: I have no idea what "compute table" is supposed to mean, you can apply that on any result if you e.g. use a CTE or wrap your select into a derived table.

Answer (score 1):

I should have spend little more time reading docs.

```
select date, cost
nth_value(cost, 7)
over(order by date desc
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
as previous_week
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_NTH_WF.html

Comment: An original postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html . Redshift is not really postgres.